# ¿Cómo consumir web service JsonArrayRequest Android Studio con Java?

Tags: java, mysql, android, android-studio, webservice

Tengo el siguiente código para consumir un web service en AS:

```
public void buscarRegistro (String URL) {
    JsonArrayRequest buscarRegistro = new JsonArrayRequest(
            Request.Method.GET,
            URL,
            null,
            new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "FUNCIONA", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    for (int i = 0; i < response.length(); i ++) {
                        try {
                            JSONObject objeto = new JSONObject(response.get(i).toString());
                            subcreditoTextView.setText(objeto.getString("NOMBRE"));
                        } catch (JSONException e){
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                }
            },
            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "NO FUNCIONA", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
    );
    requestQueque.add(buscarRegistro);
}
```

Este método se llama al hacer "touch" desde botón:

```
consultaButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        buscarRegistro("http://127.0.0.1/WorkspaceApp/models/buscar_registro.php?numeroSubcredito=AN79960234001206");
    }
});
```

Pero se va por el ErrorListener que contiene el TOAST, tengo la dependencia

```
implementation 'com.android.volley:volley:1.2.1'
```

El permiso en el manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```

Así como la relación de variables con los recursos en pantalla

```
// DECLARACION RECURSO A VARIABLE
private EditText subcreditoEditText;
private TextView subcreditoTextView;
private Button consultaButton;
private RequestQueue requestQueque;

// ENLACE RECURSO A VARIABLE
subcreditoEditText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.subcreditoEditText);
subcreditoTextView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.subcreditoTextView);
consultaButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.consultaButton);
requestQueque = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
```

Y los import

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.android.volley.Request;
import com.android.volley.RequestQueue;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.JsonArrayRequest;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;
```

Cabe mencionar que la petición al servidor la valide en el navegador, también les dejo el código

```
<?php
    require('../database/database.php');
    $numeroSubcredito = $_GET['numeroSubcredito'];
    $query = "SELECT * FROM bujic_workspace.subcreditos WHERE SUBCREDITO = '$numeroSubcredito' LIMIT 1";
    $resultado = $conexionBaseDatos -> query($query);
    while ($fila = $resultado -> fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
        $producto [] = array_map('utf8_encode', $fila);
    }
    echo json_encode($producto);
    $resultado -> close();
```

Estoy usando Android Studio Dolphin, PHP 7.3.26, MySQl

Comment: Hola @Minor, no sé si ya encontraste la respuesta. Honestamente no tengo idea de como ayudarte ya que para conexiones con servicios opte por usar Retrofit (un framework que me ayuda a consumir apis de manera sencilla). Mi respuesta es muy subjetiva pero te recomiendo usarlo te dejo el link para que lo mires si te llama la atención: https://square.github.io/retrofit/

Comment: Hola @GustavoMora, lamentablemente no encontré la respuesta, por más que investigue en Internet, estuve con varios tutoriales pero según todo estaba bien, no tengo idea que sucedió. Deja reviso sobre Retrofit ¡Gracias!

Comment: Otra cosa que recién noté y espero te ayude. La dirección de tu API es http://127.0.0.1... Dicha dirección en tu navegador te debe de responder siempre porque corresponde a "localhost". Pero si usas un emulador o un telefono fisico, la misma dirección corresponde a "localHost" del emulador o del telefono fisico donde el api no se encuentra publicado. Espero te haga sentido esta observación. Igualmente si quieres probar un api publico yo siempre uso este como para testing https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/